# Displaying remaining contents after a particular number of characters in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, string, laravel-5

I have a description containing more than 100 characters. I am trying to limit the description with 50 characters and will show a read more button.

```
{!! str_limit($prgm['description'],50,"...") !!} 
@if(strlen($prgm['description']) > 50)
<button id="readmore">Read more</button>
@endif
```

What I need to take next is, after clicking on read more, I need to display the rest of the characters after the 50th character.Is there any default function to do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to show read more data in same page or another page??

Comment: same page itself, when I click read more, i need to display the contents as a continuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need anymore default function to do this. After click button "Read more" you can use ajax call to back-end with link or id parameter to get all character of this description. And when ajax callback return value,you just change text by using jquery.